# Phone Gap 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: device'

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I am very new to PhoneGap yet have not been able to get some sample code to run properly.  I believe I have went through the entire setup process properly, but perhaps I am missing something.

I get the following error.

```
file:///android_asset/www/js/pg.js Line: 107: ReferenceError: Can't find variable device
```

Here is the javascript which produces the error.

```
var info = [
        { name : 'Device Name',     value : device.name },
        { name : 'Device PhoneGap',     value : device.phonegap },
        { name : 'Device Platform',     value : device.platform },
        { name : 'Device UUID',     value : device.uuid },
        { name : 'Device Version',  value : device.version }
    ];
```

The above should not be executed until the DOM is ready, so all scripts are loaded properly before this is executed.

This code works fine with an IPhone Simulator and XCode, however it fails with Android Emulator on Eclipse.  The droidgap javascript is included before this script and I have made sure that it is loading.  My guess is the real problem is somewhere on the Java side of things, but I cannot pinpoint it.  I'm not sure what other details I can include.  If you have any questions I will try to reply promptly.  I'm welcoming any suggestions at this point.

EDIT:
This line of code also fails inside the onDeviceReady function

```
navigator.notification.alert("Device Ready.");
```

Comment: I know you mentioned that all scripts are loaded properly, but just to double check: this means that this script is executed on "deviceready" and not "onload" event?

Comment: I have put in console.log to ensure that deviceready executes, it does execute and I have it loading a twitter feed which also executes fine.

Comment: Okay this was, as I thought, a really stupid mistake.  I was using the assets my coworker sent from the iphone.  I was using the phonegap javascript for Iphone and not the one for Android which of course broke everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Iphone phonegap javascript instead of the Android javascript, causing nothing to work.

Comment: I'm using the correct version of all js files and still receiving this error when trying to implement push notifications for iOS

Comment: @KamalSalem Me too, have you solved your problem yet?

Comment: There are several causes to this problem.  Be sure the references to your javascript files are correct.